# python iterate from 0 to any Integer, positive or negative

Tags: python

I have to iterate from 0 to any Integer (call it x) that can be positive or negative (0 and x both included) (whether I iterate from x to 0 or from 0 to x does not matter)
I know I can use an if-else statement to first check if x is positive or negative and then use `range(x+1)` if x>0 or `range(x, 1)` if x<0 (both will work when x=0) like:

```
if x >= 0:
    for i in range(x+1):
        pass
else:
    for i in range(x, 1):
        pass
```

but I want a better way especially since I will actually be iterating over 2 Integers and this code is messy (and here also whether I iterate from y to 0 or from 0 to y does not matter)

```
if (x >= 0) and (y >= 0):
    for i in range(x+1):
        for j in range(y+1):
            pass
elif (x >= 0) and (y < 0):
    for i in range(x+1):
        for j in range(y, 1):
            pass
elif (x < 0) and (y >= 0):
    for i in range(x, 1):
        for j in range(y+1):
            pass
else:
    for i in range(x, 1):
        for j in range(y, 1):
            pass
```

Comment: Depends on how you use `i` and `j` inside the loop. As it stands (from what you've posted), you may as well just use `range(abs(x)+1)` and `range(abs(y)+1)`.

Comment: `abs` won't work as I want negative values if x,y<0, and Python does not have a `sign` function so that I can multiply `i`,`j` with the `sign(x)`,`sign(y)`

Comment: Like I said - "Depends on how you use `i` and `j` inside the loop". You haven't shown that in your code, hence, as it stands, you may as well use `abs`. If you'd like to show how exactly you're using `i` and `j` inside the loop, then we might be able to give you better advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution that requires no functions

```
for i in range(min(x, 0), max(x, 0) + 1):
    for j in range(min(y, 0), max(y, 0) + 1):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it by defining a function.

```py
get_range_args = lambda x: (0, x+1) if x > 0 else (x, 1)
for i in range(*get_range_args(x)):
    for j in range(*get_range_args(y)):
        pass
```

Comment: @user16714199 this is probably the cleanest solution

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1:

```
x = -9
y = 1
def getPosNeg(num):
    if num >= 0:
         return f"0, {num+1}"
    return f"{num}, 1"
x_eval = eval(getPosNeg(x)) # use eval
y_eval = eval(getPosNeg(y)) # use eval
for i in range(*x_eval):
    for j in range(*y_eval):
        print(i, j)
```

Approach 2:

```
x = -9
y = 1

def getPosNeg(num):
    if num >= 0:
         return (0, num+1)
    return (num, 1)
x_eval = getPosNeg(x)
y_eval = getPosNeg(y)
for i in range(*x_eval):
    for j in range(*y_eval):
        print(i, j)
```

If you only want positive integers in range, use `abs()`:

```
x = -9
y = 1

for i in range(abs(x+1)):
    for j in range(abs(y+1)):
        print(i, j)
```

Docs:
[eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: `eval` is generally evil. Most certainly for something like this, which doesn't seem to require using it.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb I intent to provide all possible solutions, so that they can know the capabilities of the language.